# How can I make a loop to draw a sequence of projections on two lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I want to draw this problem: Given distinct straight lines $O A$ and $O B$. From a point in $O B$ a perpendicular is drawn to $O A$; from the foot of this perpendicular a line is drawn perpendicular to $O B$. From the foot of this second perpendicular a line is drawn perpendicular to $O A$; and so on indefinitely.
I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=5;r=4.5;},line cap=butt,line join=round]
\path (0,0) coordinate (O)
(0:R) coordinate(A)
(30:R) coordinate(B)
(30:r) coordinate(M)
coordinate (H) at ($(O)!(M)!(A)$)
coordinate (K) at ($(O)!(H)!(B)$)
coordinate (L) at ($(O)!(K)!(A)$)
coordinate (P) at ($(O)!(L)!(B)$)
coordinate (Q) at ($(O)!(P)!(A)$)
coordinate (R) at ($(O)!(Q)!(B)$)
coordinate (S) at ($(O)!(R)!(A)$)
coordinate (T) at ($(O)!(S)!(B)$)
;   
\foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/90,O/-90,M/90,H/-90,K/90,L/-90,P/90,Q/-90,R/90,S/-90,T/90}
\path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$}; 
\draw (A) -- (O) --(B) (M) -- (H) -- (K) -- (L) -- (P) --(Q) -- (R) --(S)--(T); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

How can I make a loop to draw this?

Comment: Is there a rule for how the letters are chosen?

Comment: No. Better is `A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n` on the line `OA` and `B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n` on the line `OB`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Idea is to name every new projected point `M` as well as, this will overwrite the previous coordinate and can be used in the next iteration.

To alternate between the *B* and the *A* labels I'm using the PGFMath function `iseven` which gives me `0` (true), `0` (false), `1`, ….
This is why the styles `place 0` and `place 1` exist which both sort aut the placement of the node as well as their content.

Simply remove the `place …` styles, the node inside the loop's body and the label for `M` to remove the labels.

As a suggestions, for the *A* points the labels are suppressed starting from subscript 6 and for the *B* points it is 7. This is done via the `\ifnum` inside the `place …` styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={R=5; r=4.5;},
    line cap=butt,
    line join=round]
  \draw (0:R)  coordinate[label=below right:$A$, alias=A'0] (A) --
        (0,0)  coordinate[label=below      :$O$           ] (O) --
        (30:R) coordinate[label=above      :$B$, alias=A'1] (B)
        (30:r) coordinate[label=above      :$B_1$         ] (M);
  \draw[
    place 0/.style={below, node contents={$A_{#1}$}, \ifnum#1>5 coordinate\fi},
    place 1/.style={above, node contents={$B_{#1}$}, \ifnum#1>6 coordinate\fi}]
    (M) foreach[
      evaluate=\i as \isTop using iseven(\i),
      evaluate=\i as \subsc using int(ceil((\i+1)/2))]
      \i in {1, ..., 30}{
    -- ($(O)!(M)!(A'\isTop)$) coordinate (M) node [place \isTop=\subsc]
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If I only show the letters `O, A, B` and hide all another letters. How can I do?

Comment: looks like this `{$\lett$}` the part that shows the content of the node.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter, try to mute it?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter Yes, in my previous version, it was the node that places the `$\lett$`. I've changed it now to use subscripts. It is the `node [place \isTop=\subsc]`, simply remove it (and the label at `M`) and the letters won't show up anymore. You can also remove the `place X` styles then.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel isn't possible to simply the code via `[remember = \i  as \lasti (initially M)]`?

Comment: @anis Re remember: Yes, that should be right. Re iseven: No, I need the sequence (1,) 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, … for the subscript. Though I guess we could use `iseven` or `isodd` instead of `ceil` for that.

Comment: yeah, `iseven` place them correctly, but doesn't show the correct label. in the case that they only want the placement, it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 9):

Another option, with almost the same loop as Qrrbrbirlbel but using trigonometry (homothecy, more precisely). No need for the `calc` library.

**Update:** Added another function, corrected the angle (now it changes with the parameter `a` which was the plan), and extended the line *ad infinitum* (well, actually only 20 steps).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{
  every node/.style={execute at end node=\strut},
  declare function={a=30;R=5;r=4.5;dist(\x,\y)=r*sin(a)*pow(cos(a),2*\x-2+\y);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=butt,line join=round]
\path (0,0) coordinate (O)
      (0:R) coordinate (A)
      (a:R) coordinate (B)
      (a:r) coordinate (M);
\draw (A) node[below] {$A$} -- (O) node[left] {$O$} -- (B) node[above] {$B$};
\draw (M) node[above] {$B_1$} foreach[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)]\i in {1,...,20}
{
   --++ ( -90:{dist(\i,0)}) \ifnum\i<6 node[below] {$A_\i$}\fi
   --++ (a+90:{dist(\i,1)}) \ifnum\j<6 node[above] {$B_\j$}\fi
};
\node at (O)          [below,xshift=5mm] {$\cdots$};
\node at (O) [rotate=a,above,xshift=7mm] {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth: one needs neither `calc` nor repeated trigonometric computations nor `remember`. All one needs is a non-orthogonal coordinate system. Obviously I am not suggesting that it is "better" not to need those things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},line join=round]
  \draw[x={(8cm,0cm)},y={(30:{8cm/cos(30)})}] 
   (1.1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1.2)
   foreach \i in {1,...,14}
   {\ifodd\i\relax 
   ({pow(0.9,\i)},0) node[dot,label=below:$A_{\the\numexpr\i/2}$](p\i){}
   \else
   (0,{pow(0.9,\i-iseven(\i))}) node[dot,label=above:$B_{\the\numexpr\i/2}$](p\i){}
   \fi
   \ifnum\i>1\relax
    (p\the\numexpr\i-1\relax.center) edge (p\i.center)
   \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice proof of concept! Though, I think it is the least user friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Here (purely for comparison / diversion) is an attempt in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), that shows off an in-line `for` loop and the useful `hide()` macro that allows you to calculate things on-the-go.

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so please compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
pair A, B; % starting points
A = 300 dir 12;
B = 300 dir 40;

pair a, b; % offset vectors for the labels
a = -7 unitvector(A) rotated 90;
b = +9 unitvector(B) rotated 90;

pair A[], B[];  % the projected points
A1 = 0.9 A;
draw A1 for i = 1 upto 16:
    hide(
        B[i] = whatever[origin, B]; B[i] - A[i] = whatever * B rotated 90;
        A[i+1] = whatever[origin, A]; B[i] - A[i+1] = whatever * A rotated 90;
        if i < 7:
            label("$A_{" & decimal i & "}$", A[i] + a); 
            label("$B_{" & decimal i & "}$", B[i] + b); 
        elseif i < 10:
            label("$\cdot$", A[i] + a); 
            label("$\cdot$", B[i] + b); 
        fi
    )
    -- B[i] -- A[i+1]
endfor withcolor 2/3 red;
draw A -- origin -- B;
label.llft("$O$", origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```